# Gmail API Send Email

Tags: elixir, gmail-api, google-developers-console

I am using Bamboo to enable my website visitors to complete and send a contact form.

- I created a service account
- I granted it domain-wide authority
- I added the following scopes:
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.metadatahttps://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale
  https://mail.google.com/
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic

config

```
config :fajalobi, Fajalobi.Mailer,
       adapter: Bamboo.GmailAdapter,
       sub: "****.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
       sandbox: false

# Google auth credentials must be provided to the `goth` app
config :goth, json:  "priv/keys/****.json" |> File.read!
```

The service returns

```
Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

Anyone a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I found at that you shouldn't use the "****.iam.gserviceaccount.com" address, but just your normal account address.